# Metadata of .jpg in php

Tags: php, comments, metadata

What is the simplest way of taking the comment/s from the metadata of a .jpg and displaying it using php?

Comment: Did you try and research this *at all* before posting here? [exif_read_data](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

Comment: Search please: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP `exif_read_data()` method to retrieve metadata.

Use this reference Link -

[Ref Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

Sample Code --

```
<?php
$image = "image.jpg";
$exif = exif_read_data($image, 0, true);
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
if($key == "IFD0"){
echo "$key.$name: $val\n";
}
}
}
?>
```

> IFD0:  Mostly contains information about the camera itself, the
>   software used to edit the image, when it was last modified, etc